# Wwise: Why does the iOS system's orange dot keep being on in Wwise's iOS Integration Demo

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, audio, avaudiosession, avaudiosessioncategory

I'm using Wwise version 2019.2.8.7432. And when I compile the Integration Demo on my iPhone (iOS 14.8.2), the app asks for microphone permission on launch. The system then keeps showing the orange dot as if the app is using the microphone.

I'm pretty sure this is caused by setting the category to `AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` during Wwise initialization. However, I think just setting iOS's AudioSessionCategory to PlayAndRecord won't trigger the system's orange dot. I'm guessing this is a bug of the Wwise engine?

Does anyone have experience on this? Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: you could deactivate the audio session singleton when not using the microphone & log a bug against the framework

Comment: @RhythmicFistman What do you mean by deactivate the audio session? Like disable all the sounds? But the app will still need to play things like background music when not using microphone.

Comment: if you have background music, you could change the session category to playback only (I forget if you have to deactivate and re-activate the session). that should stop the dot

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I just tried. I initialize Wwise with `AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, then I change the system's audio session category to ambient, and the log shows that the category is correctly changed. But dot is still there. I guess the wwise engine is doing something weird internally?

Comment: `AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` won't change that, but `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` will. The orange dot is for the microphone so  `AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` will correctly keep the orange dot alive.

Answer (score 0):

`AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` won't change that, but `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` will. The orange dot is for the microphone so `AkAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` will correctly keep the orange dot alive.